# Separating data from a httpResponse body in Angular

Tags: angular, httpresponse

I am very new to Angular. I am required to separate out the 'jwt' token from the response in the component to store it in the localstorage. Can't get the response as a text since I require the response.status as well. Can someone show me how to separate it out? I tried many explanations here, but nothing seems to work out for me.

My login method;

```
checkLogin(){
this.service.generateToken(this.credentials).subscribe(
  (response) => {
    if(response.status == 200){
      this.message = "Login Successfull"
      localStorage.setItem("token",//save the token);
      this.router.navigate(['']);
    }
},
(error) => {
    this.message = "Invalid Username or Password";
});
}
```

The http service

```
public generateToken(request):Observable<any>{
return this.http.post<any>("http://localhost:8080/authenticate", request,{observe:'response'});
}
```

My Response format:

[Response Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yrl46.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are able to get `response.status` value then `response.body.jwt` would also be accessible, can you try this way

```
(response) => {
    if(response.status == 200){
      this.message = "Login Successfull"
      localStorage.setItem("token",response.body.jwt);
      this.router.navigate(['']);
    }
```